# Why do ruby gems like acts_as_taggable_on recommend specific version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, versioning

Most gems included into a rails app suggest that we include them without version, so that (I assume) bundler will take care of using the latest compatible version. However, some gems like `acts_as_taggable_on` [link](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on), recommend a specific version (`acts_as_taggable_on` recommends a specific version:

`gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 3.4'`

Is it ok to omit the specific version in general? Do I then have to change the version each time a new update is rolled out?

BTW, I understand needing a specific version when earlier versions of rails, etc. are being used. But when we have the latest rails version, do we need to add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably they gonna change a gem's interface. And it can break compatibility with the current interface of the gem.